# C# Operator Overloading Using Generic's Subclass

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading, operators

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
public struct Vector2d<T> where T : Unit {
    public double x;
    public double y;

    ...

    public static Vector2d<Length> operator * (Vector2d<Speed> speed, Vector2d<Duration> duration) {
        return new Vector2d<Length>(speed.x * duration.x, speed.y * duration.y);
    }
}
```

The Length, Speed, and Duration types are all subtypes of Unit. (T inherits from Unit as well)

However, the compiler says:

> One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type.

This strikes me as odd because the types provided are sub-classes of the containing type.

Why is what I am attempting to do illegal?

I know Vector2 is not a subclass of Vector2, but I'm not trying to use the generic type's values. All the data used in the operator is the Vector2 class.

Comment: It's illegal because the language designers made it illegal. The error message tells you exactly the constraint that the C# specification describes. The compiler is just following the specification. If you want to know "why?" you need to ask the language designers, and even then their reasoning may be based primarily on their own opinion.

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted...perfectly valid question with code and clear question. +1 from me.

Comment: I recommend against attempting to represent unit analysis via generics. Units are the sort of thing that really needs to be built into the language. See F#'s unit type annotations for example. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/units-of-measure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/watt39ff.aspx) for this error:

> A definition of a binary operator specifies both parameters with types other than that of the class or structure in which the operator is defined.
>   When you define an operator in a class or structure, at least one of the parameters must be of the type of that class or structure.

In your case, your operator does not make use of a `Vector2d<T>` type (you're using `Vector2d<Speed>` and `Vector2d<Duration>`.

Comment: So the operator has to apply to ALL the instances of the type, not just a subset. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Operators operate on instances of a type in which they are declared. For example:

```
string one = new string(new char[] { 'o', 'n', 'e' });
string two = new string(new char[] { 't', 'w', 'o' });
if (one == two) { // do something... };
```

The reason I am able to use `==` is because it is implemented in `String` class.

You also have an operator in your class. So let's use it. But to do so I need to create an instance of `Vector2d<T>` and since it is an open type, I need to close it during instantiation.

So let's do this first:

```
public class MyClass : Unit
{
}
```

Now let's create an instance of your struct:

```
var inst1 = new Vector2d<MyClass>();
var inst2 = new Vector2d<MyClass>();
```

That works because `MyClass` is passing the restriction that `T` must derive from `Unit`. Ok now I am going to use the operator:

```
// Ooops MyClass is not Speed or Duration
var result = inst1 * inst2;
```

This is exactly why the compiler is enforcing that rule because it wants to make sure the operator can operate on the instance of the type.

In your case you can only define the operator for `Vector2d<T>` like this:

```
public struct Vector2d<T> where T : Unit
{
    public double x;
    public double y;

    public Vector2d(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static Vector2d<T> operator *(Vector2d<T> speed, Vector2d<T> duration)
    {
        return new Vector2d<T>(speed.x * duration.x, speed.y * duration.y);
    }
}
```

Furthermore, your operator, the way you have it is not generic at all. It is using `Speed`, `Duration` and `Length` so you are working with those types.

The error *One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type.* is the compiler's way of avoiding us getting ourselves into such troubles. We should be thankful!